# How to format Boss RC-3 loop station

Tags: amplifiers, looper-pedals

My [Boss RC-3 loop station](http://my.boss.info/products/rc-3/), once asked to play a loop, outputs an incredibly loud white noise.

Questions:

i) Do you know possible ways of fixing this issue?

ii) If not, do you know how to format the Boss pedal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RC-3: clearing the internal memory (factory reset)

**Do not turn off the Power while the display is flashing.**

**Backup your data. Copy the complete Roland folder to your computer**

Begin with device POWER TURNED OFF:

1. Press and hold the [WRITE] and [RHYTHM ON/OFF] buttons and TURN ON the POWER by connecting a MONO INSTRUMENT cable to the OUTPUT A  L/MONO of the RC-3 OUTPUT JACK.
2. Release the buttons, and then press [RHYTHM ON/OFF] again—"FN" flashes in the display.
3. Press [WRITE]  — "FN" flashes rapidly for approximately 10 seconds.
4. When the phrase number appears, the FACTORY RESET is complete. 
   Recycle POWER OFF then back ON again for normal play mode.

**Do not turn off the Power while the display is flashing.**

Comment: It appears to have fixed the noise issue.